# Passing highscore back to main menu

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to send my high score back to the main menu. Here are my intents. However, it just crashes when trying to get back to the main menu. My logcat is also below. Any tips would be great.

GameActivity

```
public void finish(){
      Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
      returnIntent.putExtra("GAME_SCORE",(gameView.getHitCount()));
      setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
      super.finish();
    }
```

MainMenu

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent retIntent) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == SCORE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (retIntent.hasExtra("GAME_SCORE")) {
                int scoreFromGame = retIntent.getExtras().getInt("GAME_SCORE");
                tvhiScore.setText(Integer.toString(scoreFromGame));
            }
        }   
    }
```

LogCat

```
  04-29 17:53:34.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1975): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 17:53:34.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1975): Process: cct.mad.lab, PID: 1975
04-29 17:53:34.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1975): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{cct.mad.lab/cct.mad.lab.MainMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 17:53:34.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
04-29 17:53:34.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
```

Comment: What is on line 70 of `MainMenu`?

Comment: tvhiScore.setText(Integer.toString(scoreFromGame));

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to call `super.finish()`? it is probably not related with the question, but it is worth asking.

Comment: I don't understand how it's null though, the text is just being replaced which the scoreFromGame

Comment: Is `tvhiscore` being initialized?

Comment: TextView tvhiScore; is declared at the top, is this what you mean?

Comment: You need to find the `TextView` when the layout is inflated; e.g `tvhiscore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewname)`

Comment: Hi - yeah I added this TextView tvhiScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvhiScore); however it doesnt even run the game now! ill update the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Either the value of `tvhiScore` or `scoreFromGame` is null. Add a breakpoint and debug this line and find which value is null.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need returnIntent. use `getIntent()` and put extras
start your game activity in main activity with `startActivityForResult(intent,request code)`

this could help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/3487232